# Add a button value into an input field when user clicks a button and send it to php file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 10 buttons with different values I need to enter the value of the button when is clicked into a text field and after this to send the full text to php file with post How can I do that.

```
<form class="row" action="Pin.php" method='post'>
        <div class="col-xs-8 text-center" style="border-right:solid 3px #CCC">
          <h1 class="demo-section-title text-uppercase text-center">Input Your Pin Number</h1>
          <input type="text" id="userPinInput" class="form-control" />
          <!-- TABLE -->
          <div id="pinPad">               
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <td><input type="button" id="btn1" name="name[]" value="1" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-inverse"></input ></td>
                  <td><input type="button" id="btn2" name="name[]" value="2" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-inverse"></input ></td>
                  <td><input type="button" id="btn3" name="name[]" value="3" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-inverse"></input ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
```

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FDv6.png)
The reason I can't use check boxes is it must look like in the screenshot.
Second I need to send the clicked value to the text area in the screenshot.And I think is more easy to send the value of the check box to php file after I click the numbers

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. As of now, this question requires details about how your code structure is. Give us a few code snippets about what you have tried and the errors that you faced.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to copy this to a text input? You could just give your buttons a value and it will be present among the submitted data.

Comment: I give them an value you can see in the question but how to get only clicked buttons value and pass them with post to php script

Comment: As el_vanja notes, if they are named buttons within your form they will be posted automatically without needing to go into a textbox. Show your current html for the buttons, and any other relevant info so that we can give you practical help and show you the best solution to your problem, instead of suggestions and guesswork. Thanks

Comment: Ok I update the question

Comment: You updated your question but the HTML code does not contain any button element (`<button>`) and uses invalid input elements (`<input>`) with no `type` attribute specified and invalid/duplicated `name` attribute. Also the PHP code does not look correct, unless you have other elements in the form with their `name` attribute set to "name".

Comment: Ok how to do it to work you get my question I need when the inputs or buttons is clicked to send the values it will be multiple clicks to the php after prssing submit button

Comment: No, we (I, at least) did not _get_ your question, because there are quite a few things that you did not tell. For example, what should happen if you click the same button twice (or more)? Is there any reason not to use better suited elements like, for example check boxes or radio buttons? Is there any particular reason why the values should first be copied into an input element and then submitted instead of being submitted directly? Please remember it is you who is looking for help; it is your best interest to provide the information required to answer your question.

Comment: @secan the name elements are not invalid, that's what you do if you want to submit multiple values as an array. And while it would be better to specify the "type" attribute explicitly, the default is text if it isn't specified (ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

Comment: @ADyson, thanks for the clarification; it has been a while (about 17 years) since I last had to work with forms submission and PHP (version 4, at that time); maybe it is time for me to review and refresh some concepts. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have shown in your HTML is lots of textboxes which seemed have been styled to look like buttons using CSS. I don't think this is necessary. You can use regular buttons, which can still have values assigned to them. The markup of your "buttons" is also invalid.

You need to

a) create some valid HTML buttons

b) listen for each button being clicked on

c) when it's clicked, add that the value of the clicked button to the textbox

d) since it's a PIN number, use a "password" field for the textbox

e) get rid of the "name" on the buttons so those values won't be sent to the server

f) give the pin number textbox a name so that value *will* be sent to the server

Demo:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var textbox = document.querySelector("#userPinInput");
  var pinButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".pinNum");
  
  pinButtons.forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      textbox.value += this.value;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="row" action="Pin.php" method='post'>
  <div class="col-xs-8 text-center" style="border-right:solid 3px #CCC">
    <h1 class="demo-section-title text-uppercase text-center">Input Your Pin Number</h1>
    <input type="password" name="pin" id="userPinInput" class="form-control" />
    <!-- TABLE -->
    <div id="pinPad">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><button type="button" id="btn1" value="1" class="pinNum btn btn-block btn-lg btn-inverse">1</button></td>
          <td><button type="button" id="btn2" value="2" class="pinNum btn btn-block btn-lg btn-inverse">2</button></td>
          <td><button type="button" id="btn3" value="3" class="pinNum btn btn-block btn-lg btn-inverse">3</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button type="button" id="btn1" value="4" class="pinNum btn btn-block btn-lg btn-inverse">4</button></td>
          <td><button type="button" id="btn2" value="5" class="pinNum btn btn-block btn-lg btn-inverse">5</button></td>
          <td><button type="button" id="btn3" value="6" class="pinNum btn btn-block btn-lg btn-inverse">6</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button type="button" id="btn1" value="7" class="pinNum btn btn-block btn-lg btn-inverse">7</button></td>
          <td><button type="button" id="btn2" value="8" class="pinNum btn btn-block btn-lg btn-inverse">8</button></td>
          <td><button type="button" id="btn3" value="9" class="pinNum btn btn-block btn-lg btn-inverse">9</button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The full pin number from the textbox would then be available in the server when the form is submitted, by accessing `$_POST["pin"]`.